# Use of undefined var of namespaced object does not raise error

Tags: javascript

I have this object "ONE.TWO". It has public vars and functions.
I use a function

```
ONE.TWO.calc (1,2,3);
```

I have this public var  'mySolution';
And if I use :

```
 myoperation = ONE.TWO.mysolution;
```

There is no error raise on Chrome (and I have set 'pause on exceptions')

mmm Any idea to solve this ? I'd want an error detection .

Comment: Why would you expect an error to occur?

Comment: A Chrome debug error generation of course !

Comment: This is not an error in Javascript. You might want to take a look at some strongly-typed implementations like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Any undefined property of an object is simply... `undefined`. In a way, that is its' value. You cannot force an error to be thrown when accessing it. You either have to check if a property `=== undefined`, or accept that it can happen and build your code around it.

Or you can build getters for all your properties. Or one general property getter than throws an error if the requested property is undefined. But that is not very practical, so I wouldn't advise that.

EDIT: Perhaps it will be of interest to you that while you can pass an undefined property around (assign it, use as function arguments) you cannot call it as a function and access it's child properties. For example, `obj.undefinedProperty.bar` will generate an error. As will `obj.undefinedFunction()`.